# VS Code Remote SSH Connection Extension not letting me use Terminal

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, terminal

So I'm using the remote development extension to work on a school computer, and I just ran into an issue where terminal can't run. I open up a terminal window and there's no current directory shown or anything, it's just a blank tab. Has anyone run into a similar problem while using the remote developement extension?

[Here's an example of the terminal window when I try to open it, no current directory is shown or anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/089am.png)

I started running too many terminals simoultaneously without noticing and then killed all of them at once. I expected the terminals to just close and for me to be able to open a new one immediately, but two .nfs files were created in my project (which I can't delete), and now whenever I try to open terminal while SSH'd into the school computer, a blank window just appears. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue since last couple of weeks and looks like I just now solved it.

Server where I was connecting was running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Upon inspecting VSCode server logs I noticed that for some reason it tried to use libc.so.6 with version at least 2.28. On Ubuntu 18.04 last available libc.so.6 version is 2.27.

Initially I tried just installing newer libc version, but it had some issues. Next I performed Ubuntu distribution upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS, as well deleted `.vscode-servers` directory from my Ubuntu user's home dir. After that I relaunched VSCode and tried remote connection to server - and terminal again worked!

Hope that this helps for you, too!